# android nested inner class used in xml throw ClassCastException

Tags: android, xml, class, nested, classcastexception

javaCode:

```
class OutView{

   public static InView extends LinearLayout{
      ......
   }
}
```

xml:

```
 <LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/inView"
 class="com.example.test.OutView$InView"
 ..... />
```

Above all works fine,  But When I use：

```
OutView.InView inView   = (OutView.InView)this.findViewById(R.id.inView);
```

An Exception :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to com.example.test.OutView$InView

occurs.

So How to deal with it ?  Thank you for advance.

Comment: Change `<LinearLayout` to `<view` in the XML.

Comment: It causes  ClassCastException :   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Comment: No, you need a lowercase `v` in the XML. Just like in my first comment.

Comment: It works !    I  used Upercase at  the beginning .   Thank you a lot .

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to typecast the view in the same format it is defined.

Do this

```
<view
    android:id="@+id/inView"
    class="com.example.test.OutView$InView"
..... />
```

Comment: It will cause an ClassNotFoundException  : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.test.OutView.InView

Comment: @ChenQi: Please try now.

Comment: it has to be a lowercase `view`

Comment: Yes ,  Well done !  It works ! I used Upercase at the beginning . Thank you a lot